# iOS 11 uiBarButtonitems shrunk in size

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder

I have an app and it works fine on iOS 10 but on iOS 11 the UIBarButtonItems icons shrunk in size. (they are bar button custom item with an image).
I have tried to put them constraints but it didn't work. Any idea?

Thanks in advance[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6Be1.png)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Provide any code that has to do with the problem...

Comment: There isn't any code. I put the images in Interface Builder.

Comment: Then put images of the hierarchy, the constraints, the attributes the different  objects involved have. It's impossible to know what's going on with just that image.

Comment: I've added two more images.

Answer (score 0):

I found it!

XCode 9 has some bugs! In XCode 8 it works fine!. It wasn't iOS 11 bug, it's a XCode 9 bug...

regards!